# Tracking pixel in iframe PHP for registration

Tags: php

i have a page `currentpage.php` which have a link to the registration page. if the user click on that link the `currentpage.php` will show "waiting for registration complete" and on other tab a registration page will open. After registration page is successfully submitted a thankyou page will appear that contains a tracking pixel than the waiting state of `currentpage.php` will change to "registration successful". how can i do this in PHP

thankyou page will have an iframe like

```
<iframe src="tracking.php?pid=1" width="100px" height="100px">
```

I can get the pid using GET method. but how to change the status of `currentpage.php` from waiting to "registrtion succesful" 
 something like

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']))
{
  // than change status //
}
```

Comment: well, have you actually *tried* anything so far? SO is not a free coding service. we'll gladly help you out if you have trouble with your code, but we will *not* write your code *for* you.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i will have an iframe in my thankyoupage which have an id. I can get the id using GET method. but how to change the status of current page if i get the value